# Motion Tracking: status of tracked pattern in a python variable (tracked vs. not tracked)

Tags: python, tracking, motion-capture

Is it possible to have the status of a tracked pattern stored in a python variable (per frame)? For example, a pattern is successfully tracked for some frames, then the pattern is hidden behind something, afterward it is visible and successfully tracked again. Would be great to use the status of "actually tracked" vs. "pattern lost" in my python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status of a track (actually tracked vs. pattern lost) is available (per frame), stored in a [property called mute](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MovieTrackingMarker.html?highlight=mute#bpy.types.MovieTrackingMarker.mute). If the pattern is successfully tracked in a frame, the status is FALSE, if the pattern is lost, the status is TRUE.

The status of a track is available via `bpy`:

```
bpy.data.movieclips[NumberOfMovieclip].tracking.tracks[NameOfTrack].markers.find_frame(FrameNumber).mute
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible. You could probably edit the C source code to output these variables for use in your script if you wanted to though.

You can view the **Python API** section of [**this page**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.62/Motion_Tracker) to make sure if you want.